# What is involved in the consecration of a Church?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, church-local

What is actually involved in consecrating a Catholic church? Does a priest or bishop just come and say a prayer over/towards the building? If so, what is the prayer? Are there any liturgical gestures or motions that the priest/bishop has to do? I'm interested in the details

Comment: See this: [Dedication of a Church and an Altar](http://www.liturgyoffice.org.uk/Resources/Rites/RDCA.pdf) from the Sacred Congregation for the Sacraments
and Divine Worship

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solemn ceremony of dedication, or consecration of a church is found in the Roman Pontifical and is performed *de jure* by a bishop. The simpler rite, which is given in the Roman Ritual, is generally reserved to bishops, **but may be also undertaken by a priest with episcopal delegation.** I know of cases where a priest have re-consecrated a Catholic Church after the church had been desecrated with permission of the local ordinary.

The whole ceremony can be read in the [Dedication of a Church
and an Altar](http://www.liturgyoffice.org.uk/Resources/Rites/RDCA.pdf) from the Sacred Congregation for the Sacraments and Divine Worship. It is too long to go into all the details here, so I will leave it here where one can peruse this at one's leisure.

The main highlights that one should be aware of is the actual Prayer of Dedication and the **Rites of Anointing, Incensing, Covering, and Lighting the Altar**.

You can see Cardinal Seán O'Malley presiding at the Mass of Dedication of the new Saint Bonaventure Church in Manomet, MA. in this YouTube video: [Dedication of the New Saint Bonaventure Church.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQ8KflnsdzY)

Comment: I'm assuming "by a bishop" may also include a vicar or prefect apostolic?

Comment: @MattGutting That is correct.